# Calculating statistically rare events from a set of observations

Tags: python, scipy

I have a Pandas data frame as follows:

Event Location| Number of events | %age success

A | 10 | 0.5

B | 2 | 1

C | 1 | 0

D | 100 | 0.3

E | 1 | 0

F | 1 | 1

...

...

The data represent the entire population of events.  I am looking for a way to find Event Locations whose behavior is significantly different from others. Perhaps Detect samples with a high confidence of having a different mean than other Samples.

To do this I am trying to calculate the probability of getting that sample in this distribution. For example, getting 1 event with either 0 or 1 success rate is likely. However, getting lots of events away from the mean is unlikely.

I am thinking of using the t-test to find the statistical significant of that event sample in this population.

Is there a better or another way to do this? To detect locations whose events are rare?

Comment: Determining what is an [outlier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) depends greatly on the source of error. This question lacks information sufficient to even guess which method you should use.

Comment: Perhaps, "Outlier" was not the correct term. I have edited the question to reflect the difference. 

I am looking for a way to find Event Locations whose behavior is significantly different from others. Perhaps Detect samples with a high confidence of having a different mean than other Samples.

The differences are due to the inherent nature of each location

Comment: this sounds like a perfectly good question to me. Outlier diagnostics in generalized linear models. If we were treating number of events as given, then it would be just glm with family binomial, and we can look at, for example, Anscombe residuals, and check which observations have the largest residuals. If we additionally consider the number of events to be distributed as Poisson (or some other count distribution), then we have a bivariate distribution and I don't know any "canned" procedures.

Comment: this question may be better for http://statistics.stackexchange.com